# Admin - Insufficient Privileges saving Page Layout

Tags: administration, insufficient-privileges

I am logged in as the Administrator, and making a basic change to the Page Layout for a Contact.  When trying to Save, I receive the Insufficient Privileges error page.  We have not made recent changes to profiles or privileges, and just successfully made similar changes a few weeks ago.  Where to begin troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be bug with salesforce.  Kindly review KI [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002uslrQAA&title=insufficient-privileges-error-when-saving-page-layout) and for now you can try 3 possible workarounds mentioned.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well. I still had a related list on my Account layout from a managed package that we were no longer using (a Conga product). Once I removed that related list from the layout, it allowed me to make my updates without the insufficient privileges error.